# React render form in App.js from another class

Tags: reactjs

I created simple test class for form `SearchForm.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const formContainer = document.querySelector('.form-container')

class SeacrhForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      this.state = {
       keywords: '',
       city: '',
       date: ''     
      }

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
     }

    render() {
        return ( 
            <form className='search-form' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <h1>Say Hi!</h1>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

//ReactDOM.render(<SeacrhForm />, formContainer)
```

It's my `App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import './SearchForm.js';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="form-container">Test     
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

`index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import './bootstrap.min.css';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

But I don't understand how to render my form in `App.js` ?

Comment: add <SeacrhForm /> inside <div className="form-container">

Comment: I got error ` Line 9:  'SeacrhForm' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render SearchForm in App.js and import it like `import { SearchForm } from './SearchForm.js';`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { SearchForm } from './SearchForm.js';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="form-container">Test  
        <SearchForm />   
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and export it from the SeachForm file after correcting the typo,

```
class SearchForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      this.state = {
       keywords: '',
       city: '',
       date: ''     
      }

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
     }

    render() {
        return ( 
            <form className='search-form' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <h1>Say Hi!</h1>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export { SearchForm}
```

Comment: I got error ` Line 9:  'SearchForm' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef`

Comment: Something doesn't work anyway `./src/SearchForm.js
  Line 27:  'SearchForm' is not defined  no-undef`

Comment: @Heidel, you have a typo while defining you class in SearchFrom it written SeacrhForm, please correct that

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import './SearchForm.js';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="form-container">
        <SearchForm />
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I got error ` Line 9:  'SeacrhForm' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef`

Comment: Nope, it didn't help `Line 9:  'SearchForm' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef`